# Python coverage and postman

Tags: python, rest, flask, code-coverage, postman

I've built a flask restful application with what I believe to be full tests through postman. I run my tests using newman from the command line.

I'm trying to use coverage.py to determine if I've missed any code in my tests, but I can't get it to work with the external test process through newman.

I've followed the flask guidance and added a shutdown endpoint that the newman script calls at the end.  When I inspect the coverage report it basically says that all of my code hasn't been covered.

Is this even possible? Is there some other tool that would let me check coverage with my existing tests?  I really don't want to convert all my tests to python just to get a coverage figure.

Comment: What kind of tests are you doing? A coverage report is a tool mostly used with low level tests like unit tests. You on the other hand seem to access the system via HTTP with is typical for a high level tests like integration, behavior or end to end tests.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: To use `coverage.py`, your tests must be written in Python.

Longer answer: `coverage.py` works by running code (i.e. tests) and seeing which lines of code it calls.  In other words, the tests and the code to test must be in the same process. If `newman` were written in Python *and* it could invoke Flask apps, it *might* be possible.

Glimmer of hope: What might be possible is to use a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html) to run the Flask app, exercise it externally via `newman`, and then examine the profiling data to see if all the statements were called.  Alas, I'm not aware of a profiler that provides that kind of report, but it should theoretically be possible with the data it collects.